# How to get the biggest port number in Linux / CentOS

Tags: linux, bash

I'm Linux newbie. How I can get the biggest port that using in Linux? I am especially interested in CentOS.

My script is:

> netstat | grep tcp | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | tr -d [:alpha:] | tr . ' ' |  tr -d [:space:] | tr : \n | sort  -n | tail --lines=1

but it is too slow!

Comment: I don't quite understand what exactly you are asking for, but using `netstat --inet --numeric-ports` instead of `netstat` should make it a lot faster

Comment: `netstat` is slow even using @mvp's suggestion (at least on my laptop..). However you can try parse the content of files like `/proc/net/tcp` or `/proc/net/udp`

Comment: I've set short command to get the biggest port number in linux 
Here is my code : 

netstat -n | grep tcp | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 4 |tr : " " | cut -d " " -f 2 | tail --lines=1

Comment: Why? This might be useful if you were trying to find the next available port, but ports do not need to assigned sequentially. You might discover that 65535 is in use, but every smaller port is still available. Generally, what you should really be interested in is which, if any, ports are *not* in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand why would you need this, but you can use this command:

```
netstat -tn | cut -f2 -d: | cut -f1 -d' ' | sort -rn | head -1
```